# Angular 7 .net core 2.2 WebApi Windows Authentication CORS

Tags: angular, .net-core, cors, asp.net-web-api2, windows-authentication

I am using Angular 7 with .net core 2.2 and the Asp.net WebApi and attempting to use Windows Authentication to identify the user. When I post data the CORS pre flight request is blocked unless I enable Anonymous Authentication. When I enable 'Anonymous Authentication' the value of

`HttpContext.User.Identity.Name`

is null even though 'Windows Authtication' is enabled still

I have tried this using IIS Express, IIS 7.5 on local development machine and IIS 8 on Windows 2012

In Startup.cs

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
            services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

            services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("TreasuryPolicy", builder =>
            {
                builder                
                .WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowCredentials();
            }));
            services.AddCors();

            services.AddTransient<IClaimsTransformation, ClaimsLoader>();
            services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseMvc();
}
```

In both ClaimsLoader.cs and Controller adLoginName is correct when 'Windows Authentication' is enabled but when Anonymous Authentication is also selected in IIS then adLoginName is null

ClaimsLoader.cs

```
public async Task<ClaimsPrincipal> TransformAsync(ClaimsPrincipal principal)
{
      var adLoginName = (ClaimsIdentity)principal.Identity.Name;
}
```

SecurityController.cs

```
[HttpGet("HasPermission/{permissionName}")]        
public ActionResult<bool> HasPermission(string permissionName)
{
     var adLoginName = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
}
```

Comment: This error from CORS if Anonoymous Authentication is not enable: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost/authentication/api/forecasting/AddForecastItem?data=%5Bobject%20Object%5D' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: Most likely you are seeing no identity during the processing of the pre-flight request.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't see the identity for all requests i.e. on the Get request where there is no pre flight check

Comment: Keith, did you find any solution for your query

Comment: Hi, yes as below 0


It seems if you add the attribute [Authorize] to the controller or action it forces Windows Authentication when 'Enable Anonymous Authentication' and 'Enable Windows Authentication' are selected https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to enable cors:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseMvc();
    app.UseCors("TreasuryPolicy")
}
```

Additional info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: thanks but I have enabled CORS as above, I missed it from my code snippet

Answer (score 1):

It seems if you add the attribute [Authorize] to the controller or action it forces  Windows Authentication when 'Enable Anonymous Authentication' and 'Enable Windows Authentication' are selected https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio