# Blazor webassembly - windows authentication - CORS error - No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: cors, blazor, asp.net-core-webapi, blazor-webassembly

I am building a Blazor Web Assembly application with an ASP.NET Core Web API.
Now I have set windowsauthentication to true because I want to use a single sign-on.
Once I did that I am getting this CORS error with all my API calls.
Then I have added BrowserRequestCredentials.Include my httpClient in my Blazor app.
Now my GET requests to the API are working but POST, PUT and DELETE still gives me the CORS error in the browser console:

> Access to fetch at 'https://localhost:44305/api/user/3' from origin 'https://localhost:4001' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

if I test my PUT, POST, and DELETE APIs with swagger, there is no problem.

API startup - configureServices:

```
services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            string cors = Configuration["Cors"];

            options.AddPolicy("AllowAll",
                builder =>
                {
                    builder.WithOrigins(cors.Split(","))
                           .AllowAnyMethod()
                           .AllowAnyHeader()
                           .AllowCredentials();
                });
            options.DefaultPolicyName = "AllowAll";
        });
```

API startup - configure:

```
            app.UseCors("AllowAll");

        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("../swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Gmh.Api v1"));

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
```

Blazor WASM app - program.cs

```
            builder.Services.AddTransient(sp => new HttpClient(new DefaultBrowserOptionsMessageHandler(new HttpClientHandler()) // or new HttpClientHandler() in .NET 5.0
        {
            DefaultBrowserRequestCache = BrowserRequestCache.NoStore,
            DefaultBrowserRequestCredentials = BrowserRequestCredentials.Include,
            DefaultBrowserRequestMode = BrowserRequestMode.Cors,
        })
        {
            BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.Configuration["Backend:BaseAddress"]),
        });
```

Comment: I guess the OPTIONS request needs anonymous access

Comment: thanks @roeland, your comment lead me to this post and helped me solve the issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55513251/angular-7-net-core-2-2-webapi-windows-authentication-cors

Comment: You should always use [Authorize] on controllers that need it. Don't assume your webserver is handling auth. Also, maybe in the future you need a controller without authorization.

Answer (score 0):

you should use cors package install it in you api and use it as api middleware to get rid of this issue. use cors  inside app.use()

Comment: i have installed nuget package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors in the API and as you can see i have added 'addCors' in my configureServices() and added 'useCors' in my configure()

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue:

1. add this to configureServices: services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
2. set windowsauthentication and anonymousauthentication to true
3. set the [Authorize] attribute in your API controller where you want to get the User.Identity.Name